# Does SharePoint 2003 support .NET 3.5 framework?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, sharepoint-2003

I would like to know if there are any concerns that we should be aware of if we were to upgrade our SharePoint 2003 server to .NET 3.5. Does this version of SharePoint even support 3.5?

Thanks in advance.

Clint

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read this:

http://ontehfritz.wordpress.com/2008/12/03/beware-net-framework-35-sp1-and-share-point-portal-server-2003/

Comment: That link is no longer available.